# S3 Retention pricing for Standard Tier Options

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a database that is exporting to s3 lets say 10GB daily. right now the s3 has a lifecycle expiration of file for 15 days on standard tier. we are redesigning the backup to save cost on s3. what i know that minimum storage for standard tier is 30 days.

what are my options? we very rarely restore from this file since its on Development account but need it soonest if needed to retore.

Comment: [S3 Standard](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/#Performance_across_the_S3_storage_classes) has no minimum storage duration, only IA and Glacier do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no minimum storage period for data in the Standard tier of Amazon S3.

`10GB of data for 15 days @ $0.023 per GB/month = 10 * .023 * 0.5 = 11.5c`

That's not a lot of money. If you have 15 backups at any one time, that is `11.5 x 15 = $1.73/month`. Is that the cost you are wanting to minimise?

If your data is mostly a 'backup', then you could use a storage class that is cheaper for storage, but has a higher charge for data retention such as **S3 Standard-Infrequent Access** -- it is half the cost for Storage but does have a minimum chargeable period of 30 days.

So:

- If you need to access the data, use **Standard**
- If you just need to store data for a short time, use **Standard**
- If you aren't likely to access the data and you are keeping it for 30 days, use **S3 Infrequent Access**
- If you are storing for longer periods, use one of the **Glacier** storage classes

If your database is running on **Amazon RDS**, then you can **use Snapshots** instead of exporting data to Amazon S3.

Comment: thanks! sorry it is TB not GB correcting on the size. we don't access the stored backup frequency might be 4-5x a year it is from EC2 though. meaning we can save if we stored it for 30 days S3-IA vs having it every 15 days expiring the files through the lifecycle? remember it is doing backup daily and the oldest will be expired after 15 days.

Comment: Okay, so TB is 1000x GB (ish), making it $1730/month, which is much more worth saving! Each day you're paying for storage of `15 x 10TB = 150TB`, which isn't small! My first recommendation would be to **compress the data** so that it is smaller. The cost of Standard for 15 days is about the same as Infrequent Access for 30 days, so not much to be saved there.  You could consider using **Glacier** storage classes that are significantly cheaper, but they charge minimum 30 days and there are higher Request & Retrieval charges, so it might not be worthwhile.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question